# MySQL Search and Replace In Different Fields

Tags: mysql, database, search, replace, phpmyadmin

Hi I imported a bunch of driving games to my arcade website but only some land in the "Driving" category. some land in the action and adventure category be accident. I need to fix this in phpMyAdmin mysql terminal. My code is trying to search the database for keywords in my tags field and replace the entity's category from Action or whatever it might be to Driving

Here is my code, but is does not seem to work

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE tags LIKE '%truck%'
UPDATE games SET category = replace (category, "%", "Driving")
SELECT * FROM games WHERE tags LIKE '%car%'
UPDATE games SET category = replace (category, "%", "Driving")
SELECT * FROM games WHERE tags LIKE '%drive%'
UPDATE games SET category = replace (category, "%", "Driving")
SELECT * FROM games WHERE tags LIKE '%race%'
UPDATE games SET category = replace (category, "%", "Driving")
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do with `Replace`...though

Answer (score 0):

Find records with tags column containing `truck` or `car` or `drive` or `race`.

```
Update mytable
SET category = 'Driving'
where tags REGEXP 'truck|car|drive|race'
;
```

another:

```
Update mytable
SET category = 'Driving'
where tags LIKE '%truck%' 
OR LIKE '%car%' OR LIKE '%drive%' OR LIKE '%race%' 
;
```

Comment: @user2030325 Glad you got it worked. [In that case please accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark on top of the answer/near upvote buttons `:)`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)